# Parsing json data failing - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I don't know where I ma missing something but I have this

```
var myvar = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}];
```

and I tried this

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(myvar))).each(function() {  
        console.log(this.name);
});
```

But I have an error in my console : `Syntax error, unrecognized expression [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"]`

I am missing something, but I don't know what ?

Edit : in fact when I copy paste the myvar in my console and run the parsing then it works ?? But, when I refresh my page and when I retrieve myvar as so : console.log(myvar), I get [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}], without normally told by chrome's console that it is an object

Comment: `var myvar = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}];`

Comment: @Newben there's still the one in the error message? Did you not copy this directly from the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes error while copy pasting. I have the edited error message

Comment: @Newben I have `name1` and `name2` in the console now. Is the problem solved?

Comment: @Antony, no it is not solved , see my post edit

Comment: `myvar` is an array so you will have `Array[2]` in the console

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing the object.

```
var myvar = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}];
```

Comment: sorry I have edited my post (error while copy-pasting), so I always have the problem

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're serializing and then deserializing though (perhaps for testing or sanitising), but it should work now.

Comment: Quite strange, in fact if I copy paste the myvar in my console and runt he parsing then it works ?? But, when I refresh my page and when I retrive the myvar variable as so console.log(myvar), I get [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}], without normally told by chrome that it is an object

Comment: That means it's still a string

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a } at the end

```
var myvar = [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}];
```

Comment: sorry I have edited my post (error while copy-pasting), so I always have the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax :

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(myvar)).each(function() {  
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

(In fact, when I copy paste the myvar in my console and run the parsing then it works. 
But, when I refresh my page and when I retrieve myvar as so : console.log(myvar), I get [{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"}], without normally told by chrome's console that it is an object )

Answer (score 0):

That's weird; I get an error as well trying your code. It seems perfectly fine though.

Why don't you just try this:

```
jQuery(myvar).each(function () {
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

this outputs

```
name1
name2
```

in my console. This seems to be a solution for you since you're already converting the object to a string and back to an object (array).